# Using a custom repository for filling an entity field in my form instead of using query builder

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a form that consist of an **entity field** like bellow

```
$builder->add('rating', 'entity', array(
         'class' => 'MyBundle:Rating',
         'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
            },
```

In this form I can use a query builder to have a custom selection of Rating entity. 
But since I have a custom repository for Rating entity like bellow, I want to use the loadAllRoots() method in the **RatingRepository** class for filling the rating entity in my form instead of using query builder.

```
class RatingRepository extends EntityRepository 
{

    public function loadAllRoots()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT r FROM MyBundle:Rating r WHERE  r.parent IS NULL')
        ->getResult();
    }
```

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a solution would be defining my forms as a service and then injecting the entity manager. Then I can use my repositories.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services